# Почему умноженние на double[,] работает а разы быстрее чем на классе-обертке Matrix

Tags: c#, матрицы

Это простое умножение

```
static double[,] mult(double[,] a, double[,] b)
{
    var C = new double[a.GetLength(0), b.GetLength(1)];

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < C.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < C.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < a.GetLength(1); k++)
            sum += a[i, k] * b[k, j];

        C[i, j] = sum;
    }

    return C;
}
```

А этой мой класс

```
 //для открытия доступа к некоторым функцииям из класса MAtrix через точку
public static class MatrixHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод проверяет можно ли слаживать две матрицы. 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool CanAdd(this Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        return Matrix.CanAdd(A, B);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод проверяет можно ли умножать две матрицы. 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool CanMultiply(this Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        return Matrix.CanMultiply(A, B);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///Проверяет квадратна ли матрица 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsSquare(this Matrix A)
    {
        return Matrix.IsSquare(A);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверяет симметрична ли матрица 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsSymmetric(this Matrix A)
    {
        return Matrix.IsSymmetric(A);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает транспонированую матрицу
    /// </summary>
    public static Matrix GetTranspose(this Matrix A)
    {
        return Matrix.Transpose(A);
    }
}

//вся работа с матрицами
public class Matrix
{
    //сложение матриц
    static Matrix Sum(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        if (A.CanAdd(B))
        {
            Matrix Sum = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, A.Columns);

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < A.Columns; j++)
                    Sum[i, j] = A[i, j] + B[i, j];

            return Sum;
        }
        else
            throw new MatrixAddException();
    }

    //произведение матриц
    static Matrix Multiply(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        if (A.CanMultiply(B))
        {   

            return MultiplyN3(A, B);
            //return MultiplyParalelN3(A, B);

            //return MultiplyN3Transpose(A, B);
        }
        else
            throw new MatrixMultiplyException();
    }

    static Matrix MultiplyN3(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
        var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);
        DateTime b = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("zu" + (b - a).TotalSeconds);

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < C.Rows; i++)
            for (int j= 0; j < C.Columns; j++)
            {
                sum = 0;

                for (int k = 0; k < A.Columns; k++)
                    sum += A[i, k] * B[k, j];

                C[i, j] = sum;
            }
         return C;
    }

    static Matrix MultiplyParalelN3(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {

        var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);

        Func<Matrix, int, Matrix, int, double> Mult = (AA, ii, BB, jj) =>
        {
            double Sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < AA.Columns; i++)
                Sum += AA[ii, i] * BB[i, jj];

            return Sum;
        };

        Parallel.For(0, C.Rows, (i) =>
        {

            Parallel.For(0, C.Columns, (j) =>
            {

                C[i, j] = Mult(A, i, B, j);

            });

        });

        return C;

    }

    static Matrix MultiplyN3Transpose(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);

        B = B.GetTranspose();

        Func<Matrix, int, Matrix, int, double> Mult = (AA, ii, BB, jj) =>
        {
            double Sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < AA.Columns; i++)
                Sum += AA[ii, i] * BB[jj, i];

            return Sum;
        };

        Parallel.For(0, C.Rows, (i) =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < C.Columns; j++)
                C[i, j] = Mult(A,i,B,j);

        });
        return C;
    }


    //произведение матрицы на число
    static Matrix Multiply(double k, Matrix B)
    {
        var ResMatrix = Create.New(B.Rows, B.Columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < B.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < B.Columns; j++)
                ResMatrix[i, j] = k * B[i, j];

        return ResMatrix;
    }

    //переопределение сложения
    public static Matrix operator +(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        return Sum(A, B);
    }

    //переопределение умножения
    public static Matrix operator *(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        return Multiply(A, B);
    }

    public static Matrix operator *(double k, Matrix B)
    {
        return Multiply(k, B);
    }

    public static implicit operator double[,] (Matrix x)     
    {
        return x.data;
    }

    //транспонирует матрицу
    internal static Matrix Transpose(Matrix A)
    {
        var Transpose = Create.New(A.Columns, A.Rows);

        Parallel.For (0, A.Rows,(i)=>{

            for (int j = 0; j < A.Columns; j++)
                Transpose[j, i] = A[i, j];
        });
        return Transpose;
    }

    //можно ли слаживать две матрицы
    internal static bool CanAdd(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        if (A.Rows == B.Rows && A.Columns == B.Columns)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    internal static bool CanMultiply(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        if (A.Columns == B.Rows)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    //квадратна ли матрица
    internal static bool IsSquare(Matrix A)
    {
        if (A.Rows == A.Columns)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //симмтерична ли матрица
    internal static bool IsSymmetric(Matrix A)
    {
        if (!IsSquare(A))
            throw new Exception();

        var Tmatrix = Transpose(A);

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < A.Columns; j++)
                if (A[i, j] != A[j, i])
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

    //сама матрица
    double[,] data;

    private Matrix(double[,] arr)
    {
        data = (double[,])arr.Clone();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает количество строк матрицы
    /// </summary>
    public int Rows
    { get { return data.GetLength(0); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает количество столбцов матрицы
    /// </summary>
    public int Columns
    { get { return data.GetLength(1); } }

    /// <summary>
    ///Работает по аналогии с двумерным массивом 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dimension"></param>
    public int GetLength(int dimension)
    {
        return data.GetLength(dimension);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает или устанавливает элемент матрицы
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i">Строка</param>
    /// <param name="j">Столбец</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return data[i, j]; }

        set { data[i, j] = value; } 
    }

    //вложенный класс, отвечающий за создание матриц
    /// <summary>
    /// Фабрики для создания матриц
    /// </summary>
    public static class Create
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Создает квадратную нулевую матрицу n*n
        /// </summary>
        public static Matrix New(int n)
        {
            return New(n, n);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает нулевую прямоугольную матрицу 
        /// </summary>
        public static Matrix New(int rows, int columns)
        {
            var arr = new double[rows, columns];

            return new Matrix(arr);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Если уже есть двумерный массив с коэффициентами
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Вернет матрицу, полученую из массива</returns>
        public static Matrix New(double[,] MatrixArray)
        {
            return new Matrix(MatrixArray);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает единичную матрицу размера n*n
        /// </summary>
        public static Matrix Identity(int n)
        {
            var matrix = New(n);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    if (i == j)
                        matrix[i, j] = 1;

            return matrix;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает диагональную матрицу
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arr">Массив диагональных элементов</param>
        public static Matrix Diagonal(double[] arr)
        {
            var vector = Vector.Create.New(arr);
            return Diagonal(vector);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Создает диагональную матрицу
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="v">Вектор диагонильных элементов</param>
        public static Matrix Diagonal(Vector v)
        {
            var matrix = New(v.Length, v.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < v.Length; j++)
                    if (i == j)
                        matrix[i, i] = v[i];

            return matrix;

        }

    }

}
```

Обращаясь к массивам не через индексатор

```
static Matrix MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer(Matrix A, Matrix B)
{
    var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < C.Rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < C.Columns; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < A.Columns; k++)
            sum += A.data[i, k] * B.data[k, j];

        C.data[i, j] = sum;
    }

    return C;
}
```

получаем ускорение в 2 раза.

Comment: Для сравнения скорости чисто на массивах и на моем классе я использовал обычное MultiplyN3

Comment: Неужели это из-за индексатора?

Comment: Пока что я сходу вижу лишний вызов Clone()

Comment: проверяли в Release или в Debug? Возможно в дебаге код индексаторов сильно неоптимизированный.

Comment: @Zergatul Проверял. При размерах 1000*1000: на двуменрных массивах ~30с в дебаге. А в релизе самый быстрый метод умножения - MultiplyN3Transpose- дал 20с.

MultiplyN3, при использовании моего класса как он есть, при 1000*1000 в дебаге дает >120c. Это же просто...

Comment: добавил, что отсутствие индексаторов ускоряет в 2х работу класса

Comment: @kovdryavlad: А вы измеряли скорость в отладчике или нет? Отладчик замедляет работу в ~2 раза, измеряйте без него и в Release-режиме.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы измеряете время с подключённым отладчиком, и может быть даже в Debug-сборке.

Дело в том, что при подключённом отладчике компилятор для удобства отладки не выполняет многие оптимизации. Например, многие функции не инлайнятся, т. к. в этом случае их не будет видно в окне Call Stack.

Поэтому для сравнения скорости нужно компилировать код в Release-режиме, и запускать тестирующий код с командной строки.

Я воспользовался утилитой для сравнения скорости [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.htm), она показала следующий результат:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.11, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 3 [1709, Fall Creators Update] (10.0.16299.309)
Processor=Intel Core i7-6700 CPU 3.40GHz (Skylake), ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=3328123 Hz, Resolution=300.4697 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2633.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.7 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2633.0


                   Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
               MultiplyN3 | 123.7 ms | 1.247 ms | 1.166 ms |
 MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer | 124.8 ms | 1.804 ms | 1.687 ms |

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  1 ms   : 1 Millisecond (0.001 sec)
```

Второй прогон того же бенчмарка дал такие результаты:

```
                   Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
               MultiplyN3 | 124.2 ms | 1.891 ms | 1.769 ms |
 MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer | 123.5 ms | 1.457 ms | 1.363 ms |
```

Мы видим, что скорость работы практически одинакова, а разница находится в пределах погрешности измерений.

---

Вот весь тестирующий код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Benchmarks
{
    Matrix A, B;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        const int S1 = 200, S2 = 300, S3 = 250;
        double[,] adata = GetRandomSquareArray(S1, S2);
        double[,] bdata = GetRandomSquareArray(S2, S3);
        A = Matrix.Create.New(adata);
        B = Matrix.Create.New(bdata);
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    double GetRandomDouble() => -1000 + r.NextDouble() * 2000;

    double[,] GetRandomSquareArray(int m, int n)
    {
        var result = new double[m, n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                result[i, j] = GetRandomDouble();
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Matrix MultiplyN3() => Matrix.MultiplyN3(A, B);

    [Benchmark]
    public Matrix MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer() => Matrix.MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer(A, B);
}

public class Matrix
{
    static public Matrix MultiplyN3(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < C.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < C.Columns; j++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < A.Columns; k++)
                    sum += A[i, k] * B[k, j];
                C[i, j] = sum;
            }

        return C;
    }

    static public Matrix MultiplyN3WithoutIndexer(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        var C = Matrix.Create.New(A.Rows, B.Columns);

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < C.Rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < C.Columns; j++)
            {
                sum = 0;

                for (int k = 0; k < A.Columns; k++)
                    sum += A.data[i, k] * B.data[k, j];

                C.data[i, j] = sum;
            }

        return C;
    }


    double[,] data;

    private Matrix(double[,] arr) { data = (double[,])arr.Clone(); }
    public int Rows { get { return data.GetLength(0); } }
    public int Columns { get { return data.GetLength(1); } }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return data[i, j]; }
        set { data[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public static class Create
    {
        public static Matrix New(int rows, int columns)
        {
            var arr = new double[rows, columns];
            return new Matrix(arr);
        }

        public static Matrix New(double[,] MatrixArray)
        {
            return new Matrix(MatrixArray);
        }
    }
}
```